# Writing a loop in R for regression replacing independent variable for robustness check

Tags: r, loops, replace, regression

I want to run a simple logit regression in R, where my dependent variable is whether a firm charges a positive price or not, and the key independent variable is number of competitors within an x mile radius of the firm.  To operationalize the competition variable, I am looking at 1, 5, 10 and 50 miles radius.

I am not sure how to write the loop though, and the `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'radius_i' not found`  when I run the loop below.

```
circle_radius = list("1", "5", "10", "15", "50")

for (i in seq_along(circle_radius)){
    my_logit_4_r[i]  <-  glm(price_b1 ~   radius_i , 
                            data=data1,
                            family = binomial(link='logit'))
    summary(my_logit_4_r[i])
   }
```

So I am not sure how to specify the loop, as I do not want to use brute force and write the 4 regressions separately.  Would appreciate help on what error I am making.

Comment: `my_logit_4_r` is a completely different variable name than `my_logit_r`, they are not and cannot be related in any way.   Likewise, `radius_` and `radius_i` are totally different names.  You haven't defined the former.   You are correct that a loop control structure is what you want.  See `https://intro2r.com/loops.html`.

Comment: (You may be following s super-old tutorial, back in the ancient times _ did have a special meaning.   No longer.)

Comment: @BadZen   I need to use the ```(i in circle_radius)``` instead of ```(i in seq_along(circle_radius))``` to construct the independent variables that exist in my raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code a bit - first, use `get()` to use the what you are trying to call from `radius_[i]` to be a covariate in your model - though this needs to be changed to `get(paste0("radius_",i))` (assuming you have a covariate named `radius_1`, `radius_5`, and so on in your `data1` data frame. Also, you might want to remove the `seq_along(circle_radius)` and just do `circle_radius` since `seq_along` will define `i` as 1, 2, 3, 4 and removing it will define it as "1", "5", "10", and "50". You also need to define `my_logit_4_r` as a list and use double bracket `[[i]]` when assigning to the list in the loop.

Below I have made the changes to make this clearer.

Since you didnt provide sample data, I am assuming your data look like this:

```
circle_radius <- list("1", "5", "10", "50")
data1 <- data.frame(price_b1 = runif(100),
                    radius_1 = runif(100),
                    radius_5 = runif(100),
                    radius_10 = runif(100),
                    radius_50 = runif(100))
```

Try the following code:

```
my_logit_4_r <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(circle_radius))
for (i in circle_radius){
  my_logit_4_r[[i]]  <-  glm(price_b1 ~  get(paste0("radius_",i)) , 
                         data=data1,
                         family = binomial(link='logit'))
  
  summary(my_logit_4_r[[i]])
}
```

The models wont converge with my sample data, but they *attempt* to run. If this doesn't work, please provide sample data and I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works.  Also, would you know why my list would have 8 elements instead of 4 here? @jpsmith

Comment: Not with the sample provided, try sharing the `dput()` of the list?